# SEO URL and Rewrite Rule force on one domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo

I have a rewrite rule to force user to go from `example.com` to `www.example.com`. This is for SEO reasons so that I have no duplicated websites and content on my Google results.

```
 # BEGIN Spark

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  /$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|php|txt|xml|js|css|ttf|otf|ico|json|svg|)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
# END Spark
```

My question. If now people post a link `example.com/news` they always will redirect to the frontpage like `www.example.com`. How can I manage that they still can use and post short URLs like `example.com/news1` or `example.com/news2` and will redirect to `www.example.com/news1` or `www.example.com/news2` respectively.

Comment: The rule you've posted should already do what you require (that's what the `$1` backreference is for). If it's not doing that then you've perhaps put this directive in the wrong place, or it's not doing anything at all (and something else is triggering the redirect). Please include your complete `.htaccess` file with this rule in place.

Comment: Ah ok. I have added the whole .htaccess. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've put the rule in the wrong place. It needs to go *before* the internal rewrite (to the front-controller: `index.php`). eg. at the top of the file, not at the end.

By placing it last it will only correctly redirect physical directories (which includes the homepage) and static resources (images, CSS, JS, etc.). All other "short URLs" that are routed through the front-controller will be redirected to `index.php` and you'll see the "frontpage".

And... to avoid a double redirect when requesting `example.com` with  a URL that contains a trailing slash then include an absolute URL in the trailing slash removal rule and include your non-www to www rule immediately after that.

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$  https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]

# Front-controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

You will need to clear the browser cache before testing since the erroneous 301 (*permanent*) redirects will have been cached by the browser. (Test with 302 - temporary - redirects to avoid caching issues.)

*Aside:* An additional concern is that these directives are inside a `# BEGIN Spark` ... `# END Spark` code block - which makes it look as if these directives are perhaps maintained by some automated process? In which case, they might be overwritten?